# Querying based on columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

A beginner with SQL here - say I have a recipient table and I'm trying to come up with a query and sort the results by ethnicity. Usually I would do

```
select abcd
from recipient 
where ehthnicity = 'White'
```

but this table has ethnicities listed as fields (attributes) - is this a bad design?

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: Please add your table description. It's not clear what your're asking.

Comment: BTW, are you trying to sort by ethnicity or filter by ethnicity?

Comment: People can have multiple ethnicities, so multiple columns makes sense.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - that's what normalization and side tables are for :)

Comment: In a comment you wrote *"the table is a dim table so maybe that has something to do with it"*. More than maybe. It is extremely pertinent. De-normalising columns on a dimension table in a star schema is a common technique with data warehouses (that is, MASSIVE databases). However, with something like Ethnicity we might expect a single column and a bitmap index to support star transformations. You should edit your question to include more information about your scenario. We can't offer any meaning advice on what you've posted so far.

Comment: the 2 tables are "individual status fact" and "recipient dim"  and the key that connects both is "recip ID". the dim table has many attributes including white, asian, aa, etc. It would make sense if there was 1 attribute named ethnicity and then the values inside of it for different races but this is not how it is and thats what confuses me. Once again database has massive amounts of data and is quite old @APC

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, it's typically a bad design. Reasons vary depending on details.
2. This data structure is called a pivot, so you want to search on how to do pivot queries if you're stuck with such a table and can't change its design.

   Example: https://databricks.com/blog/2018/11/01/sql-pivot-converting-rows-to-columns.html

   [Oracle supports PIVOT clauses](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/pivot.php), lucky for you.

Comment: the database is MASSIVE and very old, also the table is a dim table so maybe that has something to do with it. Thanks regardless

Comment: I can't offer any more specific advice as you didn't show exact table structure nor desired query output

Comment: *"the table is a dim table so maybe that has something to do with it"*. More than maybe. It is extremely pertinent. De-normalising columns on a dimension table in a star schema is a common technique with data warehouses (that is, MASSIVE databases). However, with something like Ethnicity we might expect a single column and a bitmap index to support star transformations.

Answer (score 0):

The United States Census Bureau has very well-defined definitions for ethnicity and race ([here](https://www.census.gov/mso/www/training/pdf/race-ethnicity-onepager.pdf) is a good summary).

You don't say what the source of your data is.  If it is from such a well-defined source, then separate columns can be sensible.  You could also use an association table, although you might find that mildly trickier in practice.

Why are separate columns ok in this case?  Because the columns are well-defined.  Because there are handful of them.  And because they are not changing much over time.  Is an association/junction table also a good solution.  Yes.

What I don't recommend is a list of strings.  For instance, Tiger Woods might have "white,black,indian,asian", and that is troublesome to parse and prone to error (gosh, is "white,black" the same as "black,white"?).